# authentication spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security

i'm trying to authenticate with spring security and jsf but it doesn't work, when i put my authentication information don't pass.
i tried some solutions and here is one of theme, this is my first time configuring jsf,spring security

there is my code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
public void configurationGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws  Exception {
       auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("ADMIN");
   // auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().
            authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                      .authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
                 .loginPage("/login.xhtml").loginProcessingUrl("login").failureUrl("/login.xhtml?error=true")
                      .permitAll()
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/index.xhtml");

}

@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
 return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
};
}
```

this is my login page

```
      <form action="${request.contextPath}/login" method="POST">
        <h:outputLabel value="Enter UserName:" />
        <input type="text" name="username"/><br/><br/>
        <h:outputLabel value="Enter Password:" />
        <input type="password" name="password"/> <br/><br/>         
        <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"   value="${_csrf.token}"/>           
      </form>
```

faces-config.xml

```
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <faces-config version="2.2"
          xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">
      <application>
    <el-resolver>
            org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
    </el-resolver>
   </application>
 </faces-config>
```

and this is my web.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<listener>
<listener-class>
    org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
</listener-class>
 </listener>
</web-app>
```

Comment: There is nothing jsf related in this question... Care to elaborate why you think your problem is jsf related?

Comment: i'm using jsf but with authentication i found this as a solution that's way i put it here and i try it but didn't work

Comment: This is **not** a spring jsf solution. It is plain jsp/spring/el. I think you misinterpreted a tutorial somewhere.

Comment: i was looking for a solution, i will put the jsf configuration

Comment: sorry for not being clear form the beging

Comment: Then search for a tutorial via a searchengine. Even stackoverflow has examples.

Comment: i have poste the solution, there you can find that i did search for examples ... and thank you for your help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i solve the problème by removing passwordEncoder

```
 @Bean
 public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
   return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
  };
```

and because i'm using spring security 5 i added {noop} before my password like this

```
 auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("{noop}admin").roles("ADMIN");
```

Comment: Great you solved it, but still nothing jsf related in the question (posting a faces config does not make jsf part of the problem) nor in the answer. And not using a pw encoder seems dangerous

Comment: the problem i was doing the some thing before with spring MVC and every things work when i try it with jsf a get the problem that's way i thought that was JSF problem and thank you for -1

Comment: The -1 is not mine, although I think the solution of not using a passwordencoder is very bad and this should not be **the** answer to your problem)

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot is a standalone server, JSF is a WEB frontend framework. The first you should integrate both. For easy start use https://github.com/joinfaces/joinfaces .

Comment: There is no requirement to use springboot with JSF. You can use them separately.

Comment: Of course JSF by itself does not need Spring or Spring boot. Sprig boot can be used as a backend service, but also possible integrate JSF with Spring and deploy under Tomcat or integrate JSF with Spring boot and run as standalone web application.